# Why are all the plots identical when plotting list of plots generated by loop?

Tags: r

The code below should generate five different plots contained in the list called plist. Why are all the plots identical when calling grid.arrange? The variable df changes at every iteration in the loop.

```
library(gridExtra)
plist <- list()
for (i in 1:5){
    df <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=rnorm(10))
    plist[[i]] <- qplot(df$y, geom="histogram")
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plist, ncol=2))
```

Comment: ggplot is lazy and doesn't evaluate until you print. `df` is defined and evaluated in the parent frame by `qplot`, so by the time you print, you have over-written the data (data which won't be used until you print the figure). Add `rm(df)` at the end of your loop and also in @balter's loop to see the difference in `qplot` and `ggplot`

Comment: @rawr good answer. makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, yes this makes sense. Many of these scripting languages defer plotting until the very last, such as Python and Matlab, requiring a drawnow() function or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but the problem is with `qplot` because this works in making different plots:

```
library(gridExtra)
plist <- list()
for (i in 1:5){
  df <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=rnorm(10))
  plist[[i]] <- #qplot(df$y, geom="histogram")
    ggplot(df, aes(x = y))+geom_histogram()
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plist, ncol=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have answer either, but this works also with `qplot`.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

plist <- list()

for (i in 1:5) {
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = rnorm(10))
  plist[[i]] <- qplot(y, data = df, geom = "histogram")
}

do.call("grid.arrange", c(plist, ncol=2))
```